# Create a closed notebook

Tags: notebooks

When using `nb = CreateDocument[]`, is there an option that prevents the notebook from opening automatically? And is there a command that opens the notebook when needed?
(I know there is a `Visible` option, but this is not actually closing the document. The reason I want this is that I want to create a document with Initialization cells, and then close and reopen the document to have the initialization cells evaluated.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a closed notebook called **demo.nb** containing an expression :-

```
content = ToString[FullForm[ToBoxes[Defer[
      Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
      ]]]];

Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "demo.nb"}],
 StringJoin["Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[", content, "
  ],\"Input\"]
  },WindowSize->{615,750},
  WindowMargins->{{328,Automatic},{Automatic,76}},
  StyleDefinitions->\"Default.nb\"
  ]"], "Text"]
```

Then, to open :-

```
nb = NotebookOpen[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "demo.nb"}]];
```

And even evaluate :-

```
SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
SelectionEvaluate[nb]
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure whether this fits your needs, but what about:

```
nb = CreateWindow[Visible -> False]
```

which creates an invisible window here on Linux. You can even work with the notebook through the kernel, e.g. `NotebookWrite[nb, "Plot[x,{x,0,1}]"]`

And when you need the window you do

```
SetOptions[nb, Visible -> True]
```

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar The Visible option does not really solves the problem. The reason I want the notebook to be closed and then reopened is that I want to have the Initilization cells created to be evaluated after its been reopened

Comment: @Yituo, Fair enough - halirutan and I attempted to answer your originally formulated question which didn't mention the initialisation cells.

Answer (score 4):

Although @halirutan has already provided an answer using `CreateWindow`, for completeness you *can* also use `CreateDocument` (see the **Examples**/**Options** section of the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateDocument.html)).  You have to provide an initial expression for the notebook:

```
nb = CreateDocument[{}, Visible -> False]
```

creates an invisible empty notebook.  Then use the same formulation to make it visible:

```
SetOptions[nb, Visible -> True]
```